# viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear methods are not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a programmatically created `UIViewController` named as "VC" and on top of that I need to load my existing `UIViewController`.

I used below code to do that, and it's working fine.
I can see my existing `UIViewController` on "VC" but not detecting any of `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` in existing view controller.

I am getting data from `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` so all the time my existing view controller collection view is empty.

```
ExistingViewController* presObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"oad"];

[vc.view addSubview:presObj.view];
[self addChildViewController:presObj];
[presObj didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, If you are loading like this then your ViewDidLoad () of existing view controller will load, and you can put a condition (if needed) then you can call ViewDidAppear () ViewWillAppear() like below

```
 existingviewcontroller *obj=[[existingviewcontroller alloc]init];
        [obj viewWillAppear:YES];
        [obj viewDidAppear:YES];
```

This will work

Comment: No, don't do this. You should not explicitly call `viewWillAppear:` or other lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialize the storyboard class?

```
self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

so all the time my existing ViewController collection view is empty --> are you using collection view in your code?

Comment: am doing above code in some other class where i  dynamically created VC, then try to load  existing ViewCOntrolling on top of that

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the addChildViewController. Then add that childviewcontroller view into your main view.

Just add the `[self addChildViewController:presObj];` before adding to the view subview.

```
ExistingViewController* presObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"oad"];
[self addChildViewController:presObj];
[vc.view addSubview:presObj.view];
[presObj didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Did you check your child view is adding you main view  hierarchy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20769399/3051458