# UIPageViewController' s Child View Controller has wrong lifecycle

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, lifecycle, childviewcontroller

When i close to UiPageVC, after UiPageVC's viewWillDisappear call, ChildVC's viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear function calls. At the end, UiPageVC's viewDidDisappear works.

I need to work ChildVC like normal way. When i dismiss to UiPageVC, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear of ChildVC should call.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] - preferably as a small downloadable project? It may be that there's some other mistake going on here.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753978/ios-routing-viewdidappear-to-child-view-controllers#answer-20769399), `viewWillDisappear(_:)` & `viewDidDisappear(_:)` might not get called in child view controller.

Following [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), override `viewWillDisappear(_:)` & `viewDidDisappear(_:)` in `UIPageViewController` subclass.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    children.forEach { $0.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true) }
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    children.forEach { $0.endAppearanceTransition() }
}
```